# Superfish Dropdown does not appear in IE6

Tags: jquery, superfish

I am using the superfish menu from this example:
http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples (with Supersubs).
It works great in every browser even in ie6!!
When i finished copying it to my project, everything seems fine but just IE6 makes problems. the dropdown does not appear and really cant find the problem! i even tried the same jquery version (like the example).
here is my menu: http://tvim.de/cmsms/
do you guys know whats wrong??
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, you have a sneaky problem:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#navi ul").supersubs({ 
        minWidth: 12,
        maxWidth: 27, 
        extraWidth: 1, // <<< RIGHT HERE, remove the comma
    }).superfish({
        autoArrows:false, 
        dropShadows: false, 
        speed:'fast',
        animation: {opacity:'show',height:'show'} 
    });
});
```

This was called the [Trailing Comma of Death](http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/). Once I removed that, your menu began working, although you might have an issue with your second-level menus displaying.

http://jfcoder.com/test/missplacedcomma.html

Comment: wow. you are right! thank you! 2nd level appears now! but next problem: 3rd level does not appear. aaaaarrrgg